# In Eclipse with Java in Macbook, trying to commit in Git I am receiving an error Can't connect to any repository

Tags: java, git

I am in Eclipse with java in Macbook trying to create my first commit in Git but I am receiving an error, I followed all the instructions how to do it but I can't, I am attaching the error message, thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: It says "auth fail" in the error.

Comment: which means you dont have the credits to push on that git repository. check your configs

Comment: Thank you, it is clear I have this problem but I don't know how to check this credentials, the route is for a previous project and now I have my personal git account with my personal route but I always receive this message, that repository for sure it is cancelled because I no longer work for that project, so my question remains, how can I change this route and solve my problem, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error message states "authentication failed".

You are probably providing wrong credentials. Seems like you are trying to push a commit using a user named "git", which is probably invalid.

Enter the correct credentials and try again.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, it is clear I have this problem but I don't know how to check this credentials, the route is for a previous project and now I have my personal git account with my personal route but I always receive this message, that repository for sure it is cancelled because I no longer work for that project, so my question remains, how can I change this route and solve my problem, thank you for your help

Comment: Well, that wasn't your question :) 
"git remote set-url origin <url>" will accomplish what you need.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but please, next time take the time to better explain the problem. We are all busy just like you and just as we take the time to provide nice answers, you should also take the time to create lovely questions. Gluck!